# Different div, same itemscope

Tags: html, schema.org

I just started updating my website with Schema.org put one thing doesn't works out how expected it.

I want to apply the following properties to a newsarticle:

- Name
- Headline
- Articlebody
- Datepublished
- Author

  - Name
  - Url

The problem is, these properties are not all in the same div. So basicly you'll see it like:

[image]

What happens is, is when I test it with [Google Rich Snippets tester](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) the second div is placed as a property of 'webpage' instead of a property of 'newsarticle'.

How should this be fixed? Or do I have to change my whole layout?

Edit: Before you suggest, at the moment it's not possible to put div 1 and div 2 into 1 wrapper because of the rest of the layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `itemref` attribute on the same element as the `itemscope` attribute. Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test</title>
<div id="div1" itemref="dpub auth" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" >
  <div itemprop="name">Article Name</div>
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <div id="dpub" itemprop="datepublished">September 1 2012</div>
  <div id="auth" itemscope itemprop="Author" >
    <div itemprop="name">John Smith</div>
    <div itemprop="url">http:/www.example.net</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check it out in the [snippets testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=&html=%3C!DOCTYPE+html%3E%0D%0A%3Ctitle%3ETest%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv+id%3D%22div1%22+itemscope+itemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FNewsArticle%22+itemref%3D%22dpub+auth%22%3E%0D%0A++%3Cdiv+itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EArticle+Name%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%3Cdiv+id%3D%22div2%22%3E%0D%0A++%3Cdiv+id%3D%22dpub%22+itemprop%3D%22datepublished%22%3ESeptember+1+2012%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A++%3Cdiv+id%3D%22auth%22+itemscope+itemprop%3D%22Author%22+%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cdiv+itemprop%3D%22name%22%3EJohn+Smith%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A++++%3Cdiv+itemprop%3D%22url%22%3Ehttp%3A%2Fwww.example.net%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A++%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A)

Comment: Almost perfect. Only when the itemtype webpage is used datepublished and author will also be a property of webpage instead of only a property of NewsArticle. 

See this snippet: http://bit.ly/VsDhvX